# MySQL takes a long time to execute some queries and doesn't execut

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to mysql. I noticed sometimes when I run a query, it takes a long time to execute and get an error message `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

The query doesn't work and I need to restart my computer in order for my computer to work. I am wondering why this is happening and how to fix it. I am not running any complex queries. Even basic queries like DELETE a row causes this issue. I noticed this only happens when I am trying to modify the table. The issue never happens when I try retrieving data (SELECT).

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: Sounds like something is locking the table/range/row - have you checked the lock tables to see what locks are active during the wait? https://serverfault.com/questions/36260/how-can-i-show-mysql-locks

Answer (score 0):

Check the db engine of your table. If its MyISAM then it will lock entire table for any modification of data. Change the table engine to InnoDB. 
Also check if you are starting transactions which are not getting closed.
You can check the query which is getting locked by 
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;